# Edges of Hypercube

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I may have some problem with this:

Given a linear program $$\max{4x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3}$$ 

under the constraints
$$ x_1 \le 5 $$
$$ 4x_1 + 1x_2 \le 25 $$
$$ 8x_1 + 4x_2 + 1x_3 \le 125 $$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0 $$

Now I know this is the hypercube and according to the lecture notes it has $2^3 = 8$ edges.

But when I look at the polyhedron $P(A,b)$ where $A$ is the matrix with the inequality constraints and b is the righthandside, then the rank of the matrix is $3$. So I have to make $3$ out of $6$ inequalities to equalities to get a possible edge, which gives me a total of $20$ possibilites. The I have to look only for linear independant ones, is this correct? For better comprehension I tried all of them and got 7 edges. Now these are less than the program should have. My edges are

$$(5,5,0)$$
$$(5,0,85)$$
$$(5,0,0)$$
$$(0,25,25)$$
$$(0,25,0)$$
$$(0,0,125)$$
$$(0,0,0)$$

Can anybody tell me where my mistake is? Is there an easier way to find all the edges instead of trying?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly found 8 vertices of the threedimensional polyhedra $P$, not its 12 edges. All that is mechanized in Maple 2015:

```
with(PolyhedralSets):
P := PolyhedralSet([x[1] <= 5, x[1] >= 0, 4*x[1]+x[2] <= 25, 8*x[1]+4*x[2]+x[3] <= 125, x[2] >= 0, x[3] >= 0]):
Vertices(P);
```

$$ [[x[3] = 0, x[2] = 0, x[1] = 0], [x[3] = 0, x[2] = 0, x[1] = 5],[x[3] = 0, x[2] = 25, x[1] = 0],[x[3] = 0, x[2] = 5, x[1] = 5],[x[3] = 125, x[2] = 0, x[1] = 0],[x[3] = 85, x[2] = 0, x[1] = 5],[x[3] = 25, x[2] = 25, x[1] = 0],[x[3] = 65, x[2] = 5, x[1] = 5]]$$
The edges of $P$ can be found by

```
Edges(P);
```

Here is one of these:
$$ [-x[3] <= 0, x[3] <= 85, x[2] = 0, x[1] = 5] $$
The polyhedra $P$ is drawn by

```
Plot(P, axes = frame);
```

[image]

Comment: yes sorry I meant vertices but wrote edges